# Finding another series given an series of $e^x$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given series of 
$e^x$=$\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^n/n!$

find series of $e^{-x}$

Comment: Substitute $-x$ for $x$.

Comment: what if I am given cos(x)= some series. and to find cos(-x). Is it applicable to just substitute -1 to it?

Comment: Yes, it is applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace $x$ with $-x$ and you are finished